# This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly

Tags: solidity, remix, abstract

I'm trying to test out Ampleforth on Rinkbey using Remix. Here are all the files that I copy into remix.
https://github.com/cryptoghoulz/based-contracts/tree/master/contracts/v4

They compile fine, but when I deploy UFragments I get this error:

> This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's
> methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor
> correctly.

Anyone know what could be going on? Thanks!

Comment: Yes: `contract UFragments is ERC20Detailed, Ownable`, and then `contract ERC20Detailed is Initializable, IERC20`.
So you cannot deploy an instance of `UFragments`. You need to inherit this contract, and implement all functions not yet implemented (presumably, all of them are declared in `IERC20`).

Comment: @goodvibration but UFragments implements all 6 functions in IERC20...

Comment: Then look for other functions in other contracts which it inherits.

Comment: I had a same error message. Have you solved it yet? Thanks @Richard Garfield

Answer (score 42):

I had the wrong compiled file selected in the remix "deploy" drop down bar -_-
for some reason the default file is the highest one in the hierarchy

Comment: Oh Man! This just saved my day.... Thx a lot.

Comment: I'm a bit embarrased to say it took me over an hour of going over my code several times before I googled and found this answer.

Answer (score 16):

[image: Screenshot]This is certainly not a code error, not a compiler error. Just proper setting is required on IDE.
Just see left hand side, the third tab in 'CONTRACT' section select 'OWNED'

Answer (score 2):

Same problem with me selected the wrong CONTRACT file,

[image]

Select the contract file from dropdown and it will deployed